# Code for checking the type of last crossover

Tags: pine-script

I want my code to check if the last happened event is either Pitop or Pibottom then give out a signal either called bullish or bearish depending on the last event happened.

```
    Pitop = crossover(MA111, MA350) ? security + (security/100 * 10) : na
    Pibottom = crossover(MA471, EMA150) ? security + (security/100 * 10) : na
  
    Bearish = crossover(MA111, EMA150) ? security + (security/100 * 10) : na and 
    Bullish = crossover(MA111, EMA150) ? security + (security/100 * 10) : na and 
    
    plotshape(Pitop, style=shape.labeldown,size=size.normal, text="Cycle Top", color=color.orange, textcolor=color.white, location=location.absolute)
    plotshape(Pibottom, style=shape.labeldown,size=size.normal, text="Cycle Bottom", color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, location=location.absolute)
    
    plotshape(Bearish,style=shape.labeldown,size=size.normal, text= "Bearish", color=color.teal,textcolor=color.white, location=location.absolute)
    plotshape(Bullish,style=shape.labeldown,size=size.normal, text= "Bullish", color=color.teal,textcolor=color.white, location=location.absolute)
```

If last happened event is Pitop i want an output that says A so i can put it at the end of my "and" statement, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ta.barssince()` to figure out the last event. The last event should have a less value.

For example:

```
barssince_Pitop = ta.barssince(Pitop)
barssince_Pibottom = ta.barssince(Pibottom)

is_last_one_Pitop = barssince_Pitop < barssince_Pibottom
```